# Maximum Subarray using javascript

Tags: javascript, kadanes-algorithm

Given an integer array nums,

find the contiguous subarray (containing at least one number)

which has the largest sum and return its sum.

Example:

> Input: [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],
>
> Output: 6
>
> Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
>
> Inputs:[-1]
>
> Output:-1
>
> Inputs:[-2,-1]
>
> Outputs:[-1]

What i try in my JS:

```js
 
    var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    result=0
    negativenumber=[]
    for(i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]<0){
            negativenumber.push(nums[i]);
    }else{
      result+=nums[i];
    }
    }
    return result;
};
maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4])//should return 6
maxSubArray([-1])//should return -1
maxSubArray([-1,-2])//should return -1
```

Comment: [Does Kadane's Max Sub Array algorithm work on all positive integer array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926213/3082296)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Kadane's algorithm.**

```js
function maxSum(arr){
  let a1 = 0
  let a2 = arr[0]
  arr.forEach((i) => {
    a1 = Math.max(i, a1 + i)
    a2 = Math.max(a2, a1)
  })
  return a2
}
console.log(maxSum([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]))
console.log(maxSum([-1]))
console.log(maxSum([-1,-2]))
```

Comment: if i use [-1] the output should be -1.If you don't mind, could you fix some code to meet the request?

Comment: @Jacky Ok I updated

Comment: Sorry,my bad.I didn't fully said there is another request.If i use [-1,-2],the output should be -1.But your code's output is 0.Would you fix the code?

Comment: @Jacky I edited the code. Accept the answer if it helped

Comment: What's the purpose of the param `a`?

Comment: @Aladdin Nothing. I have removed it. Thanks for correction.